# Ensuring interface compliance in MobX State tree models

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have interfaces defined for my typescript server APIs and when defining models through MobX state tree I would like to ensure that the typescript compiler enforces that the model snapshots comply with these interfaces.

So if an additional property gets added to `IFoo` interface, but is not added to `Foo` MST model, it would be desirable to have typescript complain about it at compile time.

What is the best way to enforce the above ?

---

I am aware that I can get a valid typescript interface from the model itself:

```
type IFoo = typeof Foo.Type
```

I don't want to use this interface for my server APIs because:

1. It is not desirable to have things like `IObservable`, `IComplexType` etc. in API interfaces which essentially deal with snapshots (plain objects).
2. Interfaces derived thus also have method signatures for actions which are not desirable.

---

I had attempted something like:

```
// IFoo is my server interface
const T = t.model("Foo", {...})

type IT = typeof T.Type;

type ISnapshot<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: T[K];}
export const Foo : IModelType<ISnapshot<IFoo>, IT> = T;
```

But this does not seem to be working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer to go for would be to use the `.SnapshotType`
Unfortunatelly we can't provide that exactly due to a lack of conditional types in TypeScript.

Up to then you need to define your interface manually :(

Here's the issue where you can track the progress :)

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/117

Comment: Yes, after spending some time exploring on typescript it became obvious to me that I could not just rely on MST to generate the interfaces. I was primarily looking for a way to ensure that after I have written the interfaces I could ensure that they don't drift away from my model definitions.

Comment: In any case, thanks for answering and all the amazing work on MST.

Answer (score 1):

You want Foo.SnapshotType

so:

```
type IFooSnapshot = typeof Foo.SnapshotType
```

Comment: SnapshotType is not sufficient because it just maps all keys to any. So if model is `Foo = types.model({name: types.string, addresses: types.array(Address) })` the `SnapshotType` will be something like `interface {name?: any; addresses?: any}`. My API interfaces are more strict eg. `interface { name: string, addresses: [IAddress] }`

Comment: Hmm I think that them being mapped to any must be a bug, can you report it as an issue: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues and link it back here. I too have noticed that they are mapped to any but I assumed it was something to do with my setup.

Comment: Yes, it is a limitation as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871448/476712.

Answer (score 1):

As an interim solution, I have done the following:

```
import { IType } from "mobx-state-tree";

export type ISchema<T> = {[K in keyof T]: IType<any, any>;}
```

And while defining my models:

```
const schema: ISchema<IFoo> = { ... }
export const Foo = t.model("Foo", schema)
```

This isn't as typesafe as I would have liked (which is why I am not accepting this answer).

However, following this pattern consistently in all models solves my primary purpose ie. if news keys are added to API interfaces (or keys are removed) then typescript will fail to compile if my client models don't have the same keys.

Comment: What happens if you add more .props() or .views() methods after the t.model("Foo", schema) ? Then the schema wouldnt take into account those views or props? Perhaps schema is different from snapshot, in that it doesnt contain view props?

Comment: Yeah, if I use props then I will have to split IFoo into multiple interfaces and use a new types which is the union of them in my API contracts. Regarding views, it is not really an issue with me because when exchanging data with the server I will never send/receive derived data, so from the perspective of API contracts derived data exposed through views is irrelevant.

Comment: @lorefnono perhaps you could submit a PR for MST docs to add this to the Typescript section as its something that I think pretty much every TS developer is going to run into (I did) and your solution is a good interim measure until issue 117 has been sorted.